# Looking for simple solution to profile a method

Tags: java, profiling

I am looking for something simpler than JProfiler to profile a Java method, something that can hook into the JVM.

I call a method on an object (in JAVA)

```
ObjectX objectX= new ObjectX();

objectX.callSomeMethod();
```

I woudl like to be able to see all the methods and time that are called with this ocasion:

(Call tree)

```
callSomeMethod()    time took        

  - callOtherMethod()  time took         

          call other method  time took    
          call security method  time took    

  - callMethodx....        time took       

  .....
```

Is there a tool for gather this information ?

to be more clear i am looking for something more simple like SLF4J profiler

```
+ Profiler [BASIC] |
-- elapsed time [A] 220.487 milliseconds. 
-- elapsed time [B] 2499.866 milliseconds. 
-- elapsed time [OTHER] 3300.745 milliseconds.
-- Total [BASIC] 6022.568 milliseconds.
```

But on SL4j you have to manually put the code profiled in the code.

I was thinking is possible to have something similar via another profiling tool.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try googling for "java profiler" for example?

Comment: yes JProfiler but i do not have the whole call stack there

Comment: Also Visual Vm but is not for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Java Profilers](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java%20Profilers&qscrl=1). I suggest you download a demo version of [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) and use it to profile your application.

Comment: I know about java profilers ...but i am looking for something more simple...if exists that can hook to the JVM and display a tree of methods called

Comment: it seems Yourkit has something in this perspective....not what i expected but quite similar.